# What is the difference between these two syntax types? (Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, variables, syntax, methods

I'm just trying to get my head around this type of syntax

I know that the

```
[instanceOfClass  Method];
```

eg. `[myImage setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"picture.jpg"]];`

performs a method on the instance of the class.

but how does this work..

```
Variable = [Class methodName];
```

eg. `int Value = [sender intValue];`

can someone explain this to me. I get that the first example performs a method on instance of class, class or variable..

but how does the latter part work?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second example also performs a method on an instance of a class, but that method returns a value which is assigned to the value on the left side of the equation.

I'd recommend spending a little time reading the [introduction provided by Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html).  This specific question is [discussed in this part of the document](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-SW1):

> Like standard C functions, methods can return values. The following
>   example sets the variable isFilled to YES if myRectangle is drawn as a
>   solid rectangle, or NO if it’s drawn in outline form only.
>
> ```
> BOOL isFilled;
>
> isFilled = [myRectangle isFilled];
> ```

Comment: Thanks. I'm still learning and reading this new book ' Beginning Mac Programming, designed with Objective C and Cocoa'. 

It's really helpful so far but somethings just needed to be cleared up.

Is there any chance you could give me an example of what I gave you, but different and tell me what it does exactly?

Comment: Boom. There we go, thank you so much for that example, it all makes sense now. Appreciate it very much sir.

Answer (score 4):

There are instance methods (defined with a `-`) and class methods (with a `+`). Instance methods are called in instances and class methods in classes.

```
- (void)instanceMethod;
+ (void)classMethod;
```

Apart from this, you example:

```
int Value = [sender intValue];
```

Seems to be an instance method. If it's inside an action, keep in mind `sender` is just an argument:

```
- (IBAction)startWork:(id)sender
{
  ...
}
```